# Regarding python loops

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have an excerpt of code:

```
      while True:

           if a == float(b[0]):
               y = b[1]
               x.append(y)

           else: 
               a = a + 1
```

Where b is a list two columns wide. The problem is that the if statement does not iterate across all of the elements, and therefore the else statement is never reached. I was wondering how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for item in b:
   if a == float(item[0]):
      y = item[1]
      x.append(y)
   else:
      a = a + 1
```

Also, you should be aware that comparing two `float` numbers using `==` may cause unexpected behaviors:

```
  2.2 * 3.0 == 6.6
  False
  3.3 * 2.0 == 6.6
  True
```

See topics like [What is the best way to compare floats for almost-equality in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python)